# How make this work? Check all elements in array same type, with the method "every"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to resolve this problem, where I need to check if every element of an array has the same type, I need to do it with the method "every". but I don't know why my code does not work, could you help me, please? Thanks

```js
function allSameType(i) {
  return (typeof i === typeof i[0]);
}
const c = [1, 2, 3];
const d = [1, 2, 3, "4"];
console.log(c.every(allSameType));
console.log(d.every(allSameType));
```

The expected output should be True and False, but I'm getting both False

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access the first element passed in the `allSameType` as an array, but it is not the array but an element of the array.

You can pass the array to the `allSameType()` function as a third parameter, because the `Array.prototype.every` callback accepts three arguments:

1. The element (`i`)
2. The index of the element (`_`)
3. The array itself on which it is invoked. (`arr`)

```js
function allSameType(i, _, arr) {
   return (typeof i === typeof arr[0]);
}
const c = [1, 2, 3];
const d = [1, 2, 3, "4"];
console.log(c.every(allSameType));
console.log(d.every(allSameType));
```

Comment: Alright, that's it. Thank you very much for the quick answer!

Comment: @JacobS. You're welcome, please accept the answer which helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to save the type of the first element first, then use `.every` to compare every other `typeof` against that:

```js
function allSameType(arr) {
  const type = typeof arr[0];
  return arr.slice(1).every(item => type === typeof item);
}
const c = [1, 2, 3];
const d = [1, 2, 3, "4"];
console.log(allSameType(c));
console.log(allSameType(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use destructuring to get the 1st item (`first`), and the rest (`rest`), and then compare them with `Array.every()`:

```js
const allSameType = ([first, ...rest]) =>
    rest.every(item => typeof item === typeof first)

const c = [1, 2, 3];
const d = [1, 2, 3, "4"];

console.log(allSameType(c));
console.log(allSameType(d));
```